# Fast Count of Same Object within List

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an operation that will be performed MANY times and so I need it to be as fast as possible, thus I **think** keeping validations to a minimum is important here.

I'm given an image, an offset and a size; and the idea is to take the color that appears the most within the area determined by the size and offset, so far I have this:

```
Private Shared Function someFunction(image As Bitmap, offset As Point, sampleSize As Size) As Color
    Dim pixelsColors As New List(Of Color)

    For i As Integer = offset.X To offset.X + sampleSize.Width
        For j As Integer = offset.Y To offset.Y + sampleSize.Height
            pixelsColors.Add(image.GetPixel(i, j))
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

What I now need is to know what is the most repeating item within the list and choose a in the case more than one have the top count, choose a random item of those that won.

I don't even mind getting rid of the `List(Of Color)` and using some other (more appropriate) object.

### UPDATE AFTER ACCEPTING ANSWER

The idea of the answer seems good but since there are a few minor error I'll post this code for future reference for other.

```
Private Shared Function someFunction(image As Bitmap, offset As Point, sampleSize As Size) As Color
    Dim pixelsColors As New Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Color, Integer)

    For i As Integer = offset.X To offset.X + sampleSize.Width
        For j As Integer = offset.Y To offset.Y + sampleSize.Height
            Dim color As Color = image.GetPixel(i, j)
            Dim count As Integer
            If Not pixelsColors.TryGetValue(color, count) Then count = 0
            pixelsColors(color) = count + 1
        Next
    Next
    Return pixelsColors.OrderByDescending(Function(colorCount) colorCount.Value).First.Key
End Function
```

Comment: Be advised that GetPixel is very slow!  You should look at the LockBits method.  See here:  http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing a linear `List(Of Color)` you should be using a hash table which allows you to associate a `Color` with a count.  Then you con do a simple traversal at the end to discover what the highest count is

```
Dim map As New Dictionary(Of Color, Integer)

For i As Integer = offset.X To offset.X + sampleSize.Width
  For j As Integer = offset.Y To offset.Y + sampleSize.Height
    Dim color = image.GetPixel(i, j)
    Dim count As Integer
    If Not map.TryGetValue(color, count) Then
      count = 0
    End If
    map(color) = count + 1
  Next
Next

Dim mostColor = map.Max(Function(x) x.Count).Key
```

Comment: If I'd known about that `TryGetValue` method I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. I tried implementing my own solution like that using SortedList and basically handling all the logic. I like your solution, I'll just wait to see if some more answers come along. Thank you.